# ¿Cómo obtener el grupo de un usuario en linux [lenguaje C]

Tags: c, linux

mi duda es la siguiente

Como puedo obtener el grupo de un usuario en el lenguaje C.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
char *getGroup (gid_t gr){ (la cabecera de la función)

struct passwd *m;
if ((m = getpwuid(gr)) == NULL)
    return "desconocido";
return (m -> pw_gid);
}
```

Cuando compilo me salta un warning, es el siguiente:

```
warning : return makes pointer from integer without a cast 

return (m -> pw_gid);
```

Lo que tengo que hacer es obtener el grupo de el usuario, similar a lo que hace el comando ls -li en linux.

Un saludo, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplemente, tienes que hacer una llamada a [`getgrgid`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getgrgid):

```
#include <grp.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

char *getGroup( gid_t gr ) {
  struct passwd *m;
  struct group *group_info;

  if ((m = getpwuid(gr)) == NULL)
    return "desconocido";

  group_info = getgrgid( m->pw_gid );

  return strdup( group_info->gr_name );
}
```

Como ves, **copio** los datos que me interesan con `strdup( )`, puesto que sucesivas llamadas a `getgrgid( )` sobreescriben su propio *buffer* interno.